# Error about image computation

Tags: google-earth-engine

I face this error: `msConfusionMatrix (Error) Output of image computation is not definedtoo large (21 bands for 1048576 pixels = 160.0 MiB > 80.0 MiB).If this is a reduction, try specifying a larger 'tileScale' parameter.`

Here is my complete code.

```
function applyScaleFactors(img) { var ms = img.select('SR_B1', 'SR_B2', 'SR_B3', 'SR_B4', 'SR_B5', 'SR_B7').multiply(0.0000275).add(-0.2).clip(table); var tir = img.select('SR_B6').multiply(0.00341802).add(149.0).clip(table); return img.addBands(ms, null, true) .addBands(tir, null, true) } var l7 = landsat.map(applyScaleFactors) .map(function(img) { var ndvi = ms.normalizedDifference(['SR_B3', 'SR_B4']).rename('ndvi'); var ndwi = ms.normalizedDifference(['SR_B1', 'SR_B7']).rename('ndwi'); return ms.addBands(tir).addBands(ndvi).addBands(ndwi) .copyProperties(img, ['system:time_start', 'system:time_end']); }) .median(); 

Map.centerObject(table); Map.addLayer(table);

var l7 = landsat .filterBounds(table) .filterDate('2002-01-01','2003-01-01') .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUD_COVER',10)) function applyScaleFactors(img) { var ms = img.select('SR_B1', 'SR_B2', 'SR_B3', 'SR_B4', 'SR_B5', 'SR_B7').multiply(0.0000275).add(-0.2) var tir = img.select('ST_B6').multiply(0.00341802).add(149.0).clip(table); return img .addBands(ms, null, true) .addBands(tir, null, true) }

var l7 = landsat .filterBounds(table) .filterDate('2002-01-01', '2003-01-01') .map(applyScaleFactors) .map(function(img) { var ndvi = img.normalizedDifference(['SR_B3', 'SR_B4']).rename('ndvi') var ndwi = img.normalizedDifference(['SR_B1', 'SR_B7']).rename('ndwi') return img.addBands(ndvi).addBands(ndwi) .copyProperties(img, ['system:time_start', 'system:time_end']); }) .median() .clip(table)

var modis = modis_lulc .filterDate('2002-01-01','2003-01-01') .filterBounds(table) .select('LC_Type2') .toBands() .clip(table);

Map.addLayer(l7,[],'landsat_composite',false);

var vis = {min: 0, max:15, palette:['1c0dff', '05450a', '086a10', '54a708', '78d203', '009900','c6b044','dcd159','dade48','fbff13','b6ff05','27ff87', 'c24f44', 'a5a5a5', 'ff6d4c','f9ffa4']};

Map.addLayer(modis,vis,'modis_lulc',false);

var cross = ee.Image.cat([l7,modis]);

print(cross)

var training = cross.stratifiedSample({ numPoints: 300, classBand: '2002_01_01_LC_Type2', region: table, scale: 30 });

var classifier = ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest(80) .train({ features: training, classProperty: '2002_01_01_LC_Type2', inputProperties: ['SR_B1','SR_B2','SR_B3','SR_B4','SR_B5','SR_B7','ndvi', 'ndwi'] });

var classified = l7.classify(classifier);

Map.addLayer(classified,vis,'landsat_lulc',false);

var trainAccuracy = classifier.confusionMatrix(); print('Confusion matrix: ', trainAccuracy); print('Training overall accuracy: ', trainAccuracy.accuracy()); print('Training kappa coefficient: ', trainAccuracy.kappa());

// new accuracy assessment

var training = cross.stratifiedSample({ numPoints: 100, classBand: '2002_01_01_LC_Type2', region: table, scale: 30, seed: 1 });

var validated = training.classify(classifier);

print(validated)

var testAccuracy = validated.errorMatrix('2002_01_01_LC_Type2', 'classification'); print('Validation error matrix: ', testAccuracy); print('Validation overall accuracy: ', testAccuracy.accuracy()); print('Validation kappa coefficient: ', testAccuracy.kappa());

Export.image.toDrive({image:classified,description:'landCover2010',scale:15,region:table})
```

Answer (score 0):

You get too many pixels when you invoke `stratifiedSample()`. You can do what the error message states and specify `tileScale`. But in your case, it's probably enough to use fewer Landsat bands. You've included a number of them that probably won't help you with the classification:

```
var l7 = ee.ImageCollection(...
  .select(['SR_.*', 'ST_B6', 'ndvi', 'ndwi'])
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/d42b5dc078b84cd0032ff07ca2be0cef

Comment: Thank you Daniel for your answer. I check it tomorrow. You did a great help to me.